# Defining neo4j relationships

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I am trying to define relationships between nodes. Each type of node has it own csv file and the relationships are defined in a csv file as well. The nodes have an unique node id and based on the node id's the relationships are defined in the csv file. Now I am unable to define the relationships in neo4j without making new nodes for each relation. This code snippet might give some insight in what I am trying to do, although it is not correct:

```
# create relationships between entities and addresses
for i, row in dfRelationships.iterrows():
    entity_node = graph.nodes.match("Entity", name=row['node_id_start']).first()
    address_node = graph.nodes.match("Address", address=row['node_id_end']).first()
    if entity_node and address_node:
        rel_properties = {
            "start_date": row['start_date'],
            "end_date": row['end_date'],
            "sourceID": row['sourceID'],
            "status": row['status'],
            "rel_type": row["rel_type"],
            "link": row["link"]
        }
        rel = Relationship(entity_node, "Registered Address", address_node, **rel_properties)
        graph.create(rel)
```

The csv file of the relationships contain the following columns: node_id_start, node_id_end, rel_type, link, status, start_date, end_date, sourceID.

See the following picture for the instances:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/88cVJ.png

Sorry for the messy post, it's my first one :)

Comment: please also share a sample of the csv files that you are using. Thanks.

Comment: Also, please use text instead of images, to make things easier to see. For example, your relationships image at the bottom has truncated headers, and it looks like the row columns do not line up with the header columns. Using text would make everything readable and easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Some immediate issues are evident:

1. A relationship type cannot have embedded space characters (unless [escaped](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/naming/#_using_special_characters_in_names)). Use something like `REGISTERED_ADDRESS` instead of `Registered Address`. *(Relationship types [should be all-uppercased](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/naming/#_recommendations).)*
2. Is the relationship type actually supposed to come from `row["rel_type"]`? If so, use *that* instead of `Registered Address`, and do not store it in the relationship as a property.
3. The relationship map does not contain a `sourceID` property, so `row['sourceID']` will cause an error. If the property is actually supposed to be `node_id_start`, then don't store it in the relationship (i.e., the relationship would have the corresponding start node as an endpoint, so storing its id in the relationship would be redundant).